# Subdomains in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

Having problem with subdomains :(

In Routes:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.app.me'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
    Route::get('/{uri}', 'ShortnerController@redirect');
});
Route::group(['domain' => 'app.me'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
    Route::get('/{uri}', 'ShortnerController@redirect');
});
Route::group(['domain' => 'platform.app.me'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'PageController@index')->before('auth'); 
});
Route::group(array('domain'=>'agent.app.me'), function(){
Route::get('/', 'AgentController@index')->before('auth');
});
```

When I go to app.me or www.app.me it shows the SiteController@index
If I go to agent.app.me it shows AgentController@index

But the problem is if I go to platform.app.me it redirects to app.me

How to solve this?

In cPanel a managed redirections like this:

```
Subdomains.Root Domain    Document Root    Redirection
agent.app.me              /public_html     not redirected
platform.app.me           /public_html     not redirected
```

Comment: Is the method of the controller loaded or a real redirect to another URL (302)? If it is a redirect, does your `Auth` filter redirect the user to `SiteController@index`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the order. The first matched route will always be the one used. Also, if app.me is just going to use the same routes as www., why not use htaccess to force www. and have one less route group to maintain?

So, routes.php:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'platform.app.me'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'PageController@index')->before('auth'); 
});

Route::group(['domain'=>'agent.app.me'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'AgentController@index')->before('auth');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'www.app.me'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
    Route::get('/{uri}', 'ShortnerController@redirect');
});
```

Notice that I changed your use of `array()` to `[]` in the `agent.app.me` route group for consistency as you were mixing the two.

And .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    # Enforce www where not using www or a valid sub domain or tld
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|agent|platform)\.app\.(me|dev)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.app.me/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```